# Dynamic Page Layout for New & Edit

Tags: apex, visualforce

I Created a vf page and controller to override New & Edit button of Account with referencing the field API Name in Vf page. Problem I am not showing Address fields like BillingCity, BillingStreet, and other compound fields.

> If i dont use below filter it is throwing error like
>   `<apex:apex:inputField>` Metadata initialization exception!".

if i use filter to stop Address data type fields, required fields are not showing.

Controller code:

```
public class DynamicPagelayoutGenericCtrl {
    public List<LayoutSections> lstSections {get; set;} 
    public SObject sObjectRecord {get; set;} 
    public Account newObjectReference{get;set;}
    public String strLayoutFields {get; set;} 
    public Id strRecordId {get; set;}
    public String strSObject {get; set;} 
    public String strSObjectLabel {get; set;} 
    public Id RecordTypeId {get; set;} 
    public Boolean showEditView{get; set;}

    public DynamicPagelayoutGenericCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    strSObject = 'Account';

    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') != null && ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') !=''){
        showEditView= true;
        strRecordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        String strQuery = '';
        strQuery += 'SELECT Id FROM ' + strSObject + ' WHERE Id =: strRecordId'; 
        sObjectRecord = database.query(strQuery); 
        RecordTypeId = null;
        system.debug('sObjectRecord'+sObjectRecord);

    }else{
        showEditView = false;
        newObjectReference = new Account();
    }
}

public class LayoutSections {
    public String Header {get; set;} 
    public String Columns {get; set;} 
    public List<LayoutFields> Fields {get; set;} 
} 

public class LayoutFields {
    public String Field {get; set;} 
    public String isUpdatable {get; set;} 
    public String isRequired {get; set;} 
    public boolean isRender {get; set;} 
} 


public void ShowSelectedRecord() {
    system.debug('=========ShowEditMode'); 
    lstSections = (List<LayoutSections>)JSON.deserialize(strLayoutFields, List<LayoutSections>.class); 
    Schema.SObjectType token;
    if(strRecordId != null)
        token = strRecordId.getSObjectType();
    else
        token = Schema.Account.getSObjectType();

    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr = token.getDescribe(); 
    strSObject = dr.getName(); 
    strSObjectLabel = dr.getLabel(); 

    SObjectType sObjectType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(strSObject); 

    String strQuery = 'SELECT '; 
    //system.debug('=======lstSections'+ lstSections);
    for(LayoutSections objL : lstSections) { 
        List<LayoutFields> lstFieldsTemp = new List<LayoutFields>(); 

        for(LayoutFields oField : objL.Fields) { 
            if(oField.Field != null && sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey(oField.Field)){ 
                LayoutFields oLayoutFields = new LayoutFields(); 
                oLayoutFields.Field = oField.Field; 
                oLayoutFields.isUpdatable = 'true'; 
                oLayoutFields.isRequired = oField.isRequired;
                oLayoutFields.isrender = true; 
                strQuery += oField.Field + ', ';

                system.debug('**name**'+String.ValueOf(sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(oField.Field).getDescribe().getName()));
                //if(String.ValueOf(sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(oField.Field).getDescribe().getType())!= 'ADDRESS' ){
                    lstFieldsTemp.add(oLayoutFields);
                //}
            } 
        } 
        objL.Fields = lstFieldsTemp; 
        //    system.debug('=====objL.Fields' + objL.Fields); 
    } 
    if(strRecordId != null){
        strQuery += 'Id FROM ' + strSObject + ' WHERE Id =: strRecordId';
        sObjectRecord = database.query(strQuery); 

    }else {
        //strQuery += 'Id FROM ' + strSObject + ' LIMIT 1';    
        system.debug('====sObjectRecord' + sObjectRecord);
    }
}

}
```

Page Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="DynamicPagelayoutGenericCtrl">
    <script src="/soap/ajax/41.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/soap/ajax/41.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        .hideListButton {
        background: transparent url(/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png) 0 -11px no-repeat !important;
        }
        .showListButton {
        background: transparent url(/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat !important;
        }
        .pbSubheader{
        color: black !important;
        background: white !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script>

    var sObject = '{!strSObject}'; 
    var recordTypeId = '{!RecordTypeId}';
    var arrLayoutFields = new Array(); 
    var arrFields = new Array(); 
    var layoutId = '';

    window.onload = function() {
        LoadLayoutFields();
    };


    var arrLayoutFields = new Array();
    var arrFields = new Array();
    var layoutId = '';

    var recordId = '';
    function LoadLayoutFields() {
        sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
        var result = sforce.connection.describeLayout(sObject, null, null);
        console.log('sObject======='+sObject);
        console.log('recordTypeId======='+recordTypeId);        
        var layouts = result.getArray("layouts");
        console.log('layouts======='+layouts.length);
        arrLayoutFields = new Array();
        arrFields = new Array();
        layoutId = '';
        if(layouts.length > 1) {
            if(recordTypeId == '') {
                var layout = layouts[0];
                detailLayoutSections(layout.detailLayoutSections);
            }
            else {
                var recordTypes = result.getArray("recordTypeMappings");
                if(recordTypes != undefined && recordTypes != null && recordTypes != '') {
                    recordTypeMappings(recordTypes);
                }

                for (var i=0; i<layouts.length; i++) {
                    if(layoutId == layouts[i].id) {
                        var layout = layouts[i];
                        detailLayoutSections(layout.detailLayoutSections);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(layouts.length > 0) {                
            var layout = layouts[0];
            detailLayoutSections(layout.detailLayoutSections);
        }
        ShowSelectedRecordAF(JSON.stringify(arrLayoutFields));
    } 

    function recordTypeMappings(recordTypes) {
        for (var i=0; i<recordTypes.length; i++) {
            if(recordTypes[i].recordTypeId == recordTypeId) {
                layoutId = recordTypes[i].layoutId;
            }
        }
    }

    function detailLayoutSections(sections) { 
        if(sections.length == undefined) 
            sections = new Array(sections); 

        for (var i=0; i<sections.length; i++) { 
            var section = sections[i]; 
            var LayoutSection = {}; 
            arrFields = new Array(); 
            LayoutSection.Header = section.heading; 
            LayoutSection.Columns = section.columns; 
            layoutRows(section.getArray("layoutRows")); 
            LayoutSection.Fields = arrFields; 
            arrLayoutFields.push(LayoutSection); 
        } 
    } 

    function layoutRows(rows) { 
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) { 
            var row = rows[i]; 
            layoutItems(row.getArray("layoutItems")); 
        } 
    } 

    function layoutItems(items) { 
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) { 
            var item = items[i]; 
            layoutComponents(item.getArray("layoutComponents"), item.editableForUpdate, item.required); 
        } 
    } 
    function layoutComponents(components, editableForUpdate, required) { 
        if(components.length ==0){
            var LayoutFields = {}; 
            LayoutFields.Field = ''; 
            LayoutFields.isUpdatable = editableForUpdate; 
            LayoutFields.isRequired = required;
            arrFields.push(LayoutFields); 
        }
        else{
            for (var i=0; i<components.length; i++) { 
                var component = components[i]; 
                if(component.getArray("components") != null && component.getArray("components").length != 0 && component.getArray("components") != undefined && component.getArray("components") == '') 
                    layoutFields(component.getArray("components"), editableForUpdate, required);
                else { 
                    var LayoutFields = {}; 
                    LayoutFields.Field = component.value; 
                    LayoutFields.isUpdatable = editableForUpdate; 
                    LayoutFields.isRequired = required; 
                    arrFields.push(LayoutFields); 
                } 
            } 
        }
    }
    function layoutFields(fields, editableForUpdate, required) { 
        for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) { 
            var field = fields[i]; 
            var LayoutFields = {}; 
            LayoutFields.Field = field.value; 
            LayoutFields.isUpdatable = editableForUpdate; 
            LayoutFields.isRequired = required; 
            arrFields.push(LayoutFields); 
        } 
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:actionfunction name="ShowSelectedRecordAF" action="{!ShowSelectedRecord}" rerender="pb3"> 
            <apex:param name="param1" value="" assignTo="{!strLayoutFields}" />
        </apex:actionfunction>
        <apex:outputPanel id="pb3">
            <apex:outputPanel id="pb2" rendered="{!lstSections != null}">
                <apex:pageMessages />
                <apex:sectionheader title="{!strSObjectLabel} Detail" />
                <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!showEditView}">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!lstSections}" var="sec" > 
                        <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!sec.Header}"  columns="{!IF(sec.Columns == '2', 2, 1)}" collapsible="true" id="Section"> 
                            <apex:repeat value="{!sec.Fields}" var="f" > 
                                <apex:inputField value="{!sObjectRecord[f.Field]}" styleClass="{!f.Field}"/> 
                            </apex:repeat> 
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>

                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlock>

                <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!!showEditView}">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!lstSections}" var="sec" > 
                        <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!sec.Header}"  columns="{!IF(sec.Columns == '2', 2, 1)}" collapsible="true" id="Section"> 
                            <apex:repeat value="{!sec.Fields}" var="f" > 
                                <apex:inputField value="{!newObjectReference[f.Field]}" styleClass="{!f.Field}"/> 
                            </apex:repeat> 
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>

                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compound fields (like those of type `Address`) are [read-only](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_limitations.htm) and are specifically not supported by Visualforce `<apex:inputField>` or `<apex:outputField>` components.

Since you are reading the page layout itself rather than the object's describe results, you will need to build in some special-case code to break down the standard Address fields on Account and/or Contact into their component fields, replacing `BillingAddress` with `BillingStreet`, `BillingCity`, `BillingState` or `BillingStateCode` (if using State and Country Picklists) and so on. This will, course, change the layout of your Visualforce reimplementation of the page layout.